# VBA for Insert image to last empty row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have to insert images from local drive to excel. VB code is working fine, but I want to insert pictures only to the last empty row in Excel. code should check the last inserted images and it should insert the rest. I have not expertise in VBA. Please help, my code is here,,

```
Sub Front_View()
  Dim xRg As Range
  Dim S As Shape
  Dim Path As String, FName As String

    Path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\1 Master Upload"
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    For Each xRg In Range("C19", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set S = GetShapeByName(xRg)
    FName = Dir(Path & xRg & ".*")
    If FName <> "" Then
    Set S = InsertPicturePrim(Path & FName, xRg)
    End If
    If Not S Is Nothing Then
    If S.Name <> xRg Then xRg.Interior.Color = vbRed
    With xRg.Offset(0, 1)
        S.Top = .Top
        S.Left = .Left
        S.Width = .Width
        S.LockAspectRatio = False
    If S.LockAspectRatio Then
    If S.Height > .Height Then S.Height = .Height
Else
        S.Height = .Height
    End If
    End With
         S.ZOrder msoSendToBack
Else
      xRg.Offset(0, 1) = "No picture available"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
Private Function GetShapeByName(ByVal SName As String) As Shape
On Error Resume Next
Set GetShapeByName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(SName)
End Function

Private Function InsertPicturePrim(ByVal FName As String, ByVal SName As String) As Shape
  Dim P As Picture
  On Error Resume Next
  Set P = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(FName)
  If Not P Is Nothing Then
  Set InsertPicturePrim = P.ShapeRange(1)
  P.Name = SName
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: It is not clear what is your code doing right and what is not.
Please add this,  with reference to which part/s of the code are not doing its job.

Comment: Code is check for whole range, as  'Visit each used cell in column A
  For Each xRg In Range("E19", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))      
but I want , it should check only last empty row where no image found, so it should insert the missing image